# String or binary data would be truncated - Finding column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

### Issue

---

I know there have been questions on this subject but I just can't seem to get them to work for me.

I am executing a Stored Procedure and i am getting the error message - `String or binary data would be truncated.`

My table design is as follows:

```
@import_source nchar(50),
@JBJOB nchar(50),
@JBCONS nchar(50),
@JBRTC1 nchar(10),
@JBRTL1 nchar(10),
@JBRTC2 nchar(10),
@JBRTL2 nchar(10),
@JBRTC3 nchar(10),
@JBRTL3 nchar(10),
@JBRTD1 int,
@JBRTT1 int,
@JBRTD2 int,
@JBRTT2 int,
@JBRTD2 int,
@JBRTT2 int
```

The Stored Procedure I am executing is as follows:

```
exec spDataImport_INS_FJBJB1P @import_source=N'CONTROL',@JBJOB=N'01G04478X2       ',@JBCONS=N'LIC0050198',@JBRTC1=N'GB ',@JBRTL1=N'DAG ',@JBRTC2=N'TH ',@JBRTL2=N'LKR ',@JBRTC3=N'   ',@JBRTL3=N'    ',@JBRTD1=20140204,@JBRTT1=1200,@JBRTD2=0,@JBRTT2=0,@JBRTD3=0,@JBRTT3=0
```

I just can't seem to find the issue with the Stored Procedure.

Comment: What reason do you have for believing that you've isolated the problem, specifically, to the small snippets you're showing us? If possible, it could be better to build a [mcve].

Comment: Last two entries will be `@JBRTD3`,`@JBRTT3` right??

Comment: @JaydipJ - good catch, so even with the tiny amount of code were being shown here, it's not even *real* code.

Comment: This won't fix the problem but don't use `int` for dates (like `JBRTD1`). SQL Server has a `DATE` type that you should be using. Have you run the code of the stored procedure without it being *in* the SP to get the exact line number where the truncation is happening? You haven't provided enough here to know what's throwing the error.

Comment: @alroc - or `datetime2` since if your inference about dates is correct, it looks like they're also passing times across also.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you're correct, I didn't even make that connection. `JBRTD1` and `JBRTT1` should be a single `datetime2` (or `datetime`).

Comment: "I just can't seem to find the issue with the Stored Procedure" - and unlike us, you have the benefit of being able to see its code...